# How to bring back ~ / tildes for the each none line in Neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

I am using version Nvim0.7.0 and have some additional custom configuration that is setting the theme and etc. For some reason the config or the theme has overwritten the config that was given `~` for each blank lines and I can't bring back them with the following command at the end of `.init.vim` file:

`highlight NonText ctermfg=blue`

How can I bring back tildes for each blank line? Doesn't really matter the color or even the symbol itself.

```
set encoding=UTF-8
set laststatus=2
set noerrorbells
set guicursor=n-v-c-sm:block,i-ci-ve:ver25-Cursor,r-cr-o:hor20
set relativenumber
set nu
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set nohlsearch
set hidden
set smartindent
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set undofile
set incsearch
set scrolloff=8
set signcolumn=yes
set list
set listchars=tab:>-
set colorcolumn=80
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
highlight NonText ctermfg=blue
```

Is the rest of the config that I am using.

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, the tildes are not used for "blank lines", they are used for the "non lines" after the last lines of the buffer. If you expect them for "blank lines" then you can forget about it.

Comment: @romainl I have changed to "non line" since that is the right explanation that I am trying to tell. Thanks